# Al crear la carpeta dist en node no copia imagenes ni carpeta pública

Tags: nodejs, typescript, express

Estoy trabajando un back-end con Node.js, Express.js y MongDB.

Estoy utilizando Typescript para codificar.

La funcionalidad que estoy usando ahorita es subir un archivo al servidor

Este es parte del código

```
try {
    const res       = await new CategoryModel( _model ).save();
    const file: any = req.files?.image;
    if ( file ) {
        const image       = path.join( 'public', 'images', 'categories', `${ res.id }.png`).replace(/\\/g, '/');
        console.log( image );
        const imageToSave = `category-images/${ res._id }.png`;
        await file.mv( image );
        await CategoryModel.findByIdAndUpdate( res._id, { image: imageToSave } );
    }

    response = SuccessInsertion( res, startAt );
    code     = 201;
} catch( e ) {        
    const errors = ErrorMongoResult( e );
    response     = ErrorResponse( errors, startAt, e );
    code         = 500;
}
return res.status( code ).json( response );
```

Funciona muy bien, al guardar información, pero el problema es el enrutamiento del archivo.

```
const image = path.join( 'public', 'images', 'categories', `${ res.id }.png`).replace(/\\/g, '/');
```

Con esto pretendo que, el un archivo público y estático se guarden mis imagenes, imagenes específicas de categorías. Estoy utilizando `replace()` por que la ruta original, me crea la ruta con `\` y no con `/`.

Ahora, como no quiero exponer tal cual la carpeta pública, hice un alias

```
app.use('/category-images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'images', 'categories')))
```

Eso me servirá para que la ruta que estoy guardando en mongo sea esta, y no la ruta que hizo mi `path.join()`

```
const imageToSave = `category-images/${ res._id }.png`;
```

Funciona, pero tengo un problema, si subo una imagen por medio del API, las imagenes se almacenan en /public/images/categories/image.png

Cabe mencionar, cuando hago la transpilación de código con Typescript y el comando `tsc -w` me crea una carpeta `dist` la cual tiene toda la transpilación a Javascript

Es decir tengo un árbol de este tipo

```
dist
  models
  routes
  core
  index.js
models
public
routes
core
index.ts
```

Eso lo configuré en el tscconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig.json to read more about this file */

    /* Basic Options */
    // "incremental": true,                   /* Enable incremental compilation */
    "target": "es5",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
    // "lib": [],                             /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    // "allowJs": true,                       /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    // "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
    // "jsx": "preserve",                     /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
    // "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    // "outFile": "./",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
     "outDir": "./dist",  
}
```

Aquí viene el problema. Cuando subo una imagen por medio del API que ya creé, funciona bien, pero almacena la imagen a nivel de root en `/public/images/categories/image.png`
Si agarro `localhost:8000/category-image/image.png` y lo pego en el navegador, no funciona.

Di un vistazo en el dist y ohhh sorpresa, Typescript no creó la carpeta public ni su contenido, ahora si le meto mano directo a dist y creo `/dist/public/images/categories/image.png` y vuelvo a buscar la imagen con `localhost:8000/category-image/image.png` ahora si funciona.

Entonces estoy muy atorado, en, cuando yo hago `nodemon dist` para levantar el server y leer la carpeta `dist` que creó Typescript, no me reconoce la carpeta pública ni la copia, pero si yo subo una imagen con el mismo `dist` la carpeta la crea a nivel de root y no entiendo por qué, ¿No se supone que estoy ejecutando dist y en ese caso debería funcionar?

¿Qué hago?

Comment: Primero: no estarás pensando que `nodemon dist` es para ser usado en producción. Cuando generas los archivos de producción, son para luego hacer un *deploy* en tu servidor de producción, ya sea Apache2, nginx o el que dispongas.

Comment: Segundo: no existe una forma directa (mediante configuración o parámetros) de que `typescript` *copie* tus archivos de la carpeta `public`, ya que el compilador de TS sólo reconocerá los archivos que maneja por defecto (`.ts`, `.js`, `.json`, etc.), vas a tener que crear un script que se haga cargo de dicha copia y llamas al proceso de la siguiente forma: `"build": "tsc -p tsconfig.build.json && npm run copy:public"`, siendo `copy` un script que realiza la copia de la carpeta `public`. También podrías usar un *task runner* como [`Gulp`](https://gulpjs.com/). Saludos

Comment: Si, el bundle en producción no correrá con `nodemon dist` será directo como `node index.js`